# How to get last duplicate line from file using perl

Tags: perl

I'd like to get the last entry of a duplicate line from a file.
The basis for duplicate checking would be the first element from a csv.

The duplicates may or may not be adjacent.

Input file:

```
971~11
972~12
973~11
974~11
972~11
```

Expected output:

```
971~11
973~11
974~11
972~11
```

I'm not looking for a perl one-liner as I intend to write this as
a subroutine.

Thanks!

*PS:*
*I have modified this code from somewhere, but this just removes the duplicates*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

while (<STDIN>) { push (@lines, $_); }

print "-\n";

foreach my $i (@lines)
{
    @newline = split(/\||~/, $i);

    if (scalar(grep{ /$newline[0]/ } @lines) == 1)
    {
        print $i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the order of the output important?

Comment: The input must be read unsorted, but the output order doesn't matter.

Comment: Could please explain this a bit more? You want to "get" the last duplicate entry. (Do you mean to remove it or to capture it?) And by duplicate entry, you really mean duplicated first field only? Based on your supplied output I suspect that what you want is to retain the last occurrence of an entry that has a duplicated first field, and remove any entries previously seen.

Comment: Your assumption was exactly what I meant. @chakram88.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the output order doesn't matter, the easiest way to do this is to use a hash to do the duplicate removal. Something like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

sub printlast(@) {
    my %dedup;
    foreach my $line (@_) {
        my $a = (split(/\||~/, $line))[0];
        $dedup{$a} = $line;
    }
    print $dedup{$_} for keys %dedup; # or sort keys %dedup for prettier output
}

my @lines;
while (<STDIN>) { push (@lines, $_); }

print "-\n";

printlast(@lines);
```

Comment: This works great thanks! Actually i did say I don't want a one-line :)

Comment: Happy new year to you too :) (I totally misread the one-liner part in your question, sorry about that.)

Answer (score 1):

When looking to dedup, it's almost always best to use a hash.

Here's something similar to the accepted answer (since @Mat beat me to it)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -lw

use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Indent = 1;

my %seen;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split('~');
    $seen{$fields[0]} = $fields[1];
}

my @output;
while (my ($k,$v) = each %seen) {
    push @output, join('~', $k, $v);
}

print Dumper \@output;

__DATA__
971~11
972~12
973~11
974~11
972~11
```